# What does "shiv" mean (in HTML5)?

Tags: html

Greets all around

1. I'm Studying html5
2. I Understand the need for Remy's html5 shiv
3. But the ***definition*** of "shiv" is simply killing me.

What exactly **does** "shiv" mean?

thanx

sleeper

Comment: **shiv** is also synonymous with **[polyfill](http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/)**

Comment: I like to think of it as [a tool to stab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiv_(weapon)) functionality in where it wasn't expected to go.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In this case, it is a synonym for shim. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shiv):

> A synonym for Shim (computing), an application compatibility
>   workaround, e.g., HTML5_Shiv

Comment: Point for the wiki link and the full explanation **of the shim** as well. Gotta start using wiki more. The dictionaries have failed me!

Answer (score 15):

It really should be "shim", but Resig used the term "shiv". See here: http://paulirish.com/2011/the-history-of-the-html5-shiv/

Comment: Excellent article on the history of the html5 shiv...er...shim...I mean... shiv. _(dang it, Resig!)_. A point for that bit of coolness! However "hats off" to @Justin Niessner for **correctly** anticipating that I might not know what a "shim" was either.